# Parse an xml file without dups

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

How can I have the Attribute_ID in the column and Attribute_Value as value to be populated in the table.
Below is XML doc:

```
 <ExperianBureauData>
  <NetConnectResponse>
    <CompletionCode>0000</CompletionCode>
    <Products>
      <CreditProfile>
        <ARF_Report> 
          <n836_-_Premier_Attributes>
            <Record_ID>836</Record_ID>
            <Record_Length>314</Record_Length>
            <Message_Code>1</Message_Code>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL0135</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000002</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL2306</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000000</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL2336</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000000</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL5742</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000000</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL5935</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000000</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL8220</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000044</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>            
          </n836_-_Premier_Attributes>         
        </ARF_Report>
      </CreditProfile>
    </Products>
  </NetConnectResponse>
 </ExperianBureauData>
```

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT       
    -- -- -- -- <<n836_-_Premier_Attributes>/<Attribute>/
    -- -- -- -- Tbl7
    ,Tbl5.value('Attribute_Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL0135 
    ,Tbl5.value('Attribute_Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL2306 
    ,Tbl5.value('Attribute_Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL2336 
    ,Tbl5.value('Attribute_Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL5742  

FROM [dbo].[STG_XML_TstTbl]
CROSS APPLY [XMLReport].nodes('/ExperianBureauData/NetConnectResponse/Products/CreditProfile/ARF_Report/n836_-_Premier_Attributes/Attribute') AS Tbl5(Tbl5);
```

Comment: The XML document was shortened.

Comment: It's probably easier if you display how the output should look like from the sample data, in form of a table. 
#1 Does each ID becomes own column? OR #2 is it enough to have multiple rows with ID,VALUE combination? 
SQL Server generally doesn't allow dynamic number of columns...

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: The nodes XPath is selecting the `<Attribute>` elements, so naturally `Attribute_Value[1]` is going to return exactly the same value for each output column. The first row will be all `000000000`, the second row `000000002` and so on. Have you tried to use `'/ExperianBureauData/NetConnectResponse/Products/CreditProfile/ARF_Report/n836_-_Premier_Attributes'` as the initial XPath and then use `Attribute_ID` selectors to address each `Attribute_Value` element individually?

Comment: Thanks Dale - I appreciate the re-formatting.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, it worked! The latter part is exactly what I was expecting but got hung on the previous which seemed like dups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following query based on that in your question...

```sql
declare @xml xml = N' <ExperianBureauData>
  <NetConnectResponse>
    <CompletionCode>0000</CompletionCode>
    <Products>
      <CreditProfile>
        <ARF_Report> 
          <n836_-_Premier_Attributes>
            <Record_ID>836</Record_ID>
            <Record_Length>314</Record_Length>
            <Message_Code>1</Message_Code>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL0135</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000002</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL2306</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000000</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL2336</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000000</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL5742</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000000</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL5935</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000000</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute>
              <Attribute_ID>ALL8220</Attribute_ID>
              <Attribute_Value>000000044</Attribute_Value>
            </Attribute>            
          </n836_-_Premier_Attributes>         
        </ARF_Report>
      </CreditProfile>
    </Products>
  </NetConnectResponse>
 </ExperianBureauData>';

SELECT DISTINCT       
    Tbl5.value('Attribute_Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL0135 
    ,Tbl5.value('Attribute_Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL2306 
    ,Tbl5.value('Attribute_Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL2336 
    ,Tbl5.value('Attribute_Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL5742  
FROM @xml.nodes('/ExperianBureauData/NetConnectResponse/Products/CreditProfile/ARF_Report/n836_-_Premier_Attributes/Attribute') AS Tbl5(Tbl5);
```

Each column is querying the same `Attribute_Value` element, `Tbl5.value('Attribute_Value[1]','VARCHAR(20)')`, so this returns the following results:

| ALL0135 | ALL2306 | ALL2336 | ALL5742 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000000 | 000000000 | 000000000 | 000000000 |
| 000000002 | 000000002 | 000000002 | 000000002 |
| 000000044 | 000000044 | 000000044 | 000000044 |

To return values matching the output column names you need to restructure the XPath query to be like the following...

```sql
SELECT
  Tbl5.value('(Attribute[Attribute_ID="ALL0135"]/Attribute_Value)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL0135,
  Tbl5.value('(Attribute[Attribute_ID="ALL2306"]/Attribute_Value)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL2306,
  Tbl5.value('(Attribute[Attribute_ID="ALL2336"]/Attribute_Value)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL2336,
  Tbl5.value('(Attribute[Attribute_ID="ALL5742"]/Attribute_Value)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL5742,
  Tbl5.value('(Attribute[Attribute_ID="ALL5935"]/Attribute_Value)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL5935,
  Tbl5.value('(Attribute[Attribute_ID="ALL8220"]/Attribute_Value)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ALL8220
FROM @xml.nodes('/ExperianBureauData/NetConnectResponse/Products/CreditProfile/ARF_Report/n836_-_Premier_Attributes') AS Tbl5(Tbl5);
```

Which returns the results:

| ALL0135 | ALL2306 | ALL2336 | ALL5742 | ALL5935 | ALL8220 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000002 | 000000000 | 000000000 | 000000000 | 000000000 | 000000044 |